# Matplotlib inset polar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to inset a polar plot inside a normal x vs y plot in cartesian coordinate. I know that inset can be obtained through pylab.axes as illustrated in this [example](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/axes_demo.html). But I do not know how to specify this is a polar plot, possibly without any grid. Any help is welcomed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you have a working example.
The main point is to specify a new, smaller axes for the second figure

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy import randn, convolve

#data
t = np.arange(0.0, 20.0, 0.001)
r = np.exp(-t[:1000]/0.05)     
x = randn(len(t))
s = convolve(x,r)[:len(x)]*0.001
theta = 2 * np.pi * t
#
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7, 6))
#main
plt.plot(t, s)
plt.axis([0, 1, np.amin(s), 2.5*np.amax(s)])
plt.xlabel('xlabel')
plt.ylabel('ylabel')
#polar
ax = fig.add_axes([0.2, 0.47, 0.30, 0.40], polar=True, axisbg='yellow')
ax.plot(theta, t, color='blue', lw=3)
ax.set_rmax(1.0)
plt.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: @NicolaVianello  If the answer is useful then vote it up. You have a 0% acceptation rate...

Comment: @NicolaVianello I cleaned a bit the code I assembled too fast. Now I think is simpler