# Zoom in on polar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, insets

I'd like to create an inset within my `fig` which is a zoom in on part of my polar plot.

I've tried various different methods but can't seem to crack the correct way to do using `matplotlib`. My code to create the plot (from my `pandas dataframe`) is below. I've also included the plot that it produces.

```
    def plot_polar_chart_new(n, start, df, sales, title):
      HSV_tuples = [(x * 1.0 / n, 0.5, 0.5) for x in range(n)]
      RGB_tuples = map(lambda x: colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(*x), HSV_tuples)
      RGB_normalised = [tuple(n / max(t) for n in t) for t in RGB_tuples]

      figsize=(15, 15)
      fig = mpl.pyplot.figure(figsize=figsize)
      ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, polar=True)
      start = 0
      prev_count = 0

      for i, salesperson in enumerate(sales):
          count, division = (df[salesperson], df.index)
          ax.bar((division - start) * 2 * np.pi / N, height=count, width=2 * np.pi / N, color=RGB_normalised[i], bottom=prev_count, label=salesperson)
          prev_count += count

      ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, N, endpoint=False))
      ax.set_xticklabels(range(start, N + start),fontsize=20)
      ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=20)
      ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
      ax.set_theta_offset(np.pi / 2.0)
      ax.set_title(title, y=1.1, fontsize=20)
      ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.9, 1.1), loc=2)    

      mpl.pyplot.show()
```

[image: Plot created for the above code]

I'd like to create a plot inset which zooms in on part of the plot between `17` and `02`.

Please help! 
Thanks

Comment: Would [Matplotlib inset polar plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610973/matplotlib-inset-polar-plot) not work? What problem do you face?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I've seen that example but thats not what Im trying to achieve, Im trying to create a zoomed in version of the plot like [this](http://akuederle.com/matplotlib-zoomed-up-inset)

Comment: Sure, so the first step is to create the inset, which is shown in the link I provided. Once you have that you can update the question with the actual problem you are facing. Also, it's not too clear how such zoom should look for a polar plot, so you may want to explain what you're trying to achieve in more detail.